# Is it possible to change the colour of the ruler lines in Google Chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

The ruler lines in Google Chrome developer tools can be useful for checking alignment. The ruler lines are grey, which works great on a white or black background. But when your background is neither black or white the lines are very hard to see, as you can see in the image.

Is it possible to change the colour of the lines?

I've explored the developer tools settings section and not found this option.

Comment: Sounds like a very good suggestion to make on https://crbug.com.